# Close modal with jquery when submit/onclick is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a huge bootstrap modal.

```
<div className="add-date">
    <div className="modal" id="eventSelectedModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
                <div className="modal-header">
                    ....
```

I want it to close at the end of a function. So on submit I do:

```
$('#eventSelectedModal"').modal({show: false});
```

This doesn't seem to close the modal for some reason. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#eventSelectedModal').modal('toggle');
```

Or better yet

```
$('#eventSelectedModal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

Believe you put an extra ' " ' <--- quote inside your jquery selector.

```
$('#eventSelectedModal"')
```

should be

```
$('#eventSelectedModal')
```